# Magento 2 Cart Price Rule Coupon Specific Coupon Does not Apply for some porducts in Admin Order

Tags: orders, magento2.2.2, discount, coupon-codes, totals

There is an issue which I am not sure if it's a bug and I hope someone can tell me, the bellow screen shoot were taken from an order:

[image]

As you can see the product in red circled didn't apply the discount, however it was deducted from Subtotal (by the way shipping isn't included)

So:

> 84.96 - 10% = 76.464
>
> 74.96 + 19.99 = 96.454 ( which is correct) round Floor() php I assume.

Now Total Paid was Charged **£103.45** *** Which is WRONG*** From Customer account also was taken **£103.45** which isn't good.

And the reason is I think is because it this one product was not added 10% on which 69.99 should have been 6.99 **Discount Amount** but instead is **0.00**

Any one any help appreciate